# Java InputMismatchException file read in

Tags: java

the program compiles fine but then,
I get a set of errors after running the code that reads :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
at ParkRunnerClass.main(ParkRunnerClass.java:48)
```

To my understanding, this is because the data going in doesn't match with what the scanner is looking for, to counter this I tried using the try (in mycode) and catch but that didn't work.

this is a build up from my previous work that worked first try without causing me any issues, also when i check the new file it stops at :

> Number of runners is:1
>
> Runner barcode is:A0000005
>
> The name for runner is:

On its own with user input the code works fine
so the issue seems to be with the input for the name. 
I'm not certain how I should fix this.

This is the short input that is stored in file.txt,
the longer version has 10 "runners" for the sake of clarity will comment the values but these comments are not in the file

> 1 // number of runners
>
> Mary Bloggs // runner name
>
> 1996 //runner year of birth
>
> 3 i dont know what this value is for so i just take it in and put it out as is
>
> 2 i dont know what this value is for so i just take it in and put it out as is
>
> Female // runners sex
>
> 5 // laps the runner did that then sets the amount of times the loop will run
>
> Marley Park  // name of park
>
> 23.5
>
> Marley Park
>
> 22.9
>
> Marley Park
>
> 23.6
>
> Marley Park
>
> 23.0
>
> Marley Park
>
> 22.99

```
public class ParkRunnerClass
            {
                public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
{

        //Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner fileInput = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"));
        PrintStream printStreamOut = new PrintStream(new File("outputfile.txt"));

        String Sid = "A000000"; // barcode template


        //-----Park Runner ----//
        ParkRunner parkrunner1 = new ParkRunner(); // runner object

        RecordNewRun runnermm = new RecordNewRun(); //min max object

        RecordNewRun[] runners = new RecordNewRun[5]; // runner array

        float[] times = new float[runners.length]; // size of the array for calc avg min/mix
        float avg = 0;
        float sum = 0;
        int inputInt;
        int inputIntrun;
        int LapCount;



        inputIntrun = fileInput.nextInt();
        printStreamOut.println("Number of runners is:" + inputIntrun);


        do {
        parkrunner1.setRunnerId(Sid);
        printStreamOut.println("Runner barcode is: " + parkrunner1.getRunnerId()); //runner barcode checked

        parkrunner1.setName(fileInput.nextLine());
        printStreamOut.println("The name for runner is: " + parkrunner1.getName());

        parkrunner1.setAge(fileInput.nextInt());
        printStreamOut.println("runner age is:" + parkrunner1.getAge());

        inputInt = fileInput.nextInt();
        printStreamOut.println("i dont know what this number is for:" + inputInt); // used for holding int

        inputInt = fileInput.nextInt();
        printStreamOut.println("i dont know what this number is for:" + inputInt); // used for holding int

        parkrunner1.setGender(fileInput.next().charAt(0));
        printStreamOut.println("runner gender M for male F for female:" + parkrunner1.getGender());


        parkrunner1.setLaps(fileInput.nextInt());
        LapCount = parkrunner1.getLaps();
        printStreamOut.println("Laps ran by runner is:" + parkrunner1.getLaps());

        for(int i = 0; i < LapCount; i++)
            {

        parkrunner1.setParkName(fileInput.nextLine());
        printStreamOut.println("park name is: " + parkrunner1.getParkName());

        //printStreamOut.println("\nPlease enter the time taken of a park run : ");
        times[i] = fileInput.nextFloat();
        sum = sum + times[i];

        runnermm.setSum(sum);
        runnermm.setAvg(sum);
        //input.nextLine();

            }

        runnermm.getMinMax(times); // puts int array values into ohject runnermm (minmax) of RecordNewRun
        printStreamOut.println("\nThe sum of park runners time spend running is: " + runnermm.getSum());
        printStreamOut.println("\nThe average time of park runners time spent per lap is: " + runnermm.getAvg());


    }while(fileInput.hasNext());

    fileInput.close();





   }

}
```

Comment: Check the locale of the scanner. It may be a result of `dots(.)` and `commas(,)` being incompatible. Also, you can set the locale of the scanner by the [useLocale](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useLocale(java.util.Locale)) method.

Comment: i tried that didn't work, i managed to fix it by taking out certain things out of the loop and putting it in front of the line that didn't work, it turns out that the line just wasn't consumed fully so i made a variable to eat the line before name and now it works fine

Comment: Alright. If I were you, I'd add it as the solution and check. That would make the life easier for the ones facing the same issue and end up with this question -and bring you few points or badges :D

Comment: will do , just need to fix one more thing the array keeps adding all the values so i need to reset it somehow then ill post the full working  code , ty for the advice